# User specified variables as counter in a shell script loop

Tags: shell, sh

I'd like to manipulate the loop behavior using user defined counter variables. I tried passing variables as arguments and also tried hard coding them in script itself but nothing worked.

```
#!/bin/bash

start_hour=0 #can be passed as argument ($1)
end_hour=24 #can be passed as argument ($2)

for i in {$((end_hour))..$((start_hour))}
do
        echo $i
done
```

Output `{24..0}`

Comment: variable references won't work in brace expressions. use `((i=end_hour;i>=start_hour;i--))` instead

Comment: @oguzismail This worked.. Thank you!!